# What kind of loading content is this?

Tags: asp.net, html, ajax, loading

http://www.google.com/insidesearch/tipstricks/all.html
I have seen many site load its content this way. It loads all the resources first (very fast) and leaves the blank character if the text is not already loaded.
I'm so sorry, my english is so bad but I really want to know what is this method's name and can I do that in asp.net.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i did a view source of that link and i found this:-
**/* force load of image for specific section requested first */**

Its a script tag, maybe this is the thing you have to google/research

Comment: Thank you so much Nachiket Kamat